# CR10S Pro Pausing the print at a certain layer height

Tags: 3d-models, creality-cr-10

Im printing on a CR10S Pro and I can't find a way to pause the print at a certain height, to insert magnets into my print. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE!

Comment: Don't be offended, but this question may be closed by the community for being a [duplicate question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/10587/how-to-pause-a-print-to-insert-something-in-a-cavity-using-ultimaker-cura).

Comment: I have tried all of that and it didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried inserting an M600 command in your slicer post-processing? This is the command for a filament change for Marlin firmware, which the 10S Pro should be using.

Comment: @cmm You're not wrong. I figured I'd ask for a clarification before writing an answer.

Comment: Actually, now that I am trying to write the answer, I've forgotten how I did this exactly. I'll have to wait until I get home to look at the gcode file that incorporates this.

Comment: You tried everything? `G4` is supported by your printer, that works. The downside is that it specifies a fixed time, you need to get it done (filament change) in time, but it does work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pause a print to insert something in a cavity using Ultimaker Cura?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/10587/how-to-pause-a-print-to-insert-something-in-a-cavity-using-ultimaker-cura)